# How to make a RecyclerView only with documents that have in their array a number larger than X

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

My database is as follows:

[image]

If I would use a `RecyclerView`, how could I retrieve only the documents which has inside the `schedules` array the number 1908150000 (for example)?

One thing I know is that I can see the documents with the condition above using this code:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference eventRef = db.collection("Events");
eventRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        for (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult()) {
            List<Long> list = (List<Long>) documentSnapshot.get("schedules");
            for (Long listItem : list) {
                if (listItem > 1908100000) {
                    Log.d("TAG", documentSnapshot.getId());
                    break;
                 }
             }
         }
    }
});
```

And also, using a `query`, I know there is the function `whereArrayContains()` but it requires a fixed number to compare as in my case I need to make it a range.

So, is it possible to get the documents with this condition into a `RecyclerView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One thing I know is that I can see the documents with the condition above using this code.

This is not the best approach since you are getting all the documents in your `Events` collection and you do the filtering client side. I say so because everything in Firestore is about the number of reads and writes you perform. For small data sets it will solve your problem with not so much cost.

> And also, using a query, I know there is the function whereArrayContains() but it requires a fixed number to compare as in my case I need to make it a range.

Using this database schema, no, you cannot query the database and in the same time filter on a range. Unfortunately Firestore doesn't currently have such a query that can help you do that. You can filter elements on range using `whereLessThanOrEqualTo()` and `whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo()` methods but it will work only a single property not on values that exist within an array.

That being said, I encourage you to send this as a request to the Firebase team.

Comment: Thank you Alex, you solved another doubt I had related to Firestore practices.